# Count instances of overlap in two vectors in R

Tags: r, overlap

I am hoping to create a matrix that shows a count of instances of overlapping values for a grouping variable based on a second variable.  Specifically, I am hoping to determine the degree to which primary studies overlap across meta-analyses in order to create a network diagram.

So, in this example, I have three meta-analyses that include some portion of three primary studies.

```
df <- data.frame(metas = c(1,1,1,2,3,3), studies = c(1,3,2,1,2,3))

   metas studies
1     1    1
2     1    3
3     1    2
4     2    1
5     3    2
6     3    3
```

I would like it to return:

```
  v1 v2 v3
1  3  1  2
2  1  1  0
3  2  0  2
```

The value in row 1, column 1 indicates that Meta-analysis 1 had three studies in common with itself (i.e., it included three studies). Row 1, column 2 indicates that Meta-analysis 1 had one study in common with Meta-analysis 2. Row 1, column 3 indicates that Meta-analysis 1 had two studies in common with Meta-analysis 3.

Comment: The three studies are Study 1, Study 2, and Study 3. Row 2 is in reference to Meta-analysis 2's overlap with Meta-analysis 1 (column 1), Meta-analysis 2 (column 2), and Meta-analysis 3 (column 3).  Thank you for your help clarifying the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for a symmetric matrix of intersecting studies.

```r
dfspl <- split(df$studies, df$metas)
out <- outer(seq_along(dfspl), seq_along(dfspl),
             function(a, b) lengths(Map(intersect, dfspl[a], dfspl[b])))
out
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    3    1    2
# [2,]    1    1    0
# [3,]    2    0    2
```

If you need names on them, you can go with the names as defined by `df$metas`:

```r
rownames(out) <- colnames(out) <- names(dfspl)
out
#   1 2 3
# 1 3 1 2
# 2 1 1 0
# 3 2 0 2
```

If you need the names defined as `v` plus the meta name, go with

```r
rownames(out) <- colnames(out) <- paste0("v", names(dfspl))
out
#    v1 v2 v3
# v1  3  1  2
# v2  1  1  0
# v3  2  0  2
```

---

If you need to understand what this is doing, `outer` creates an expansion of the two argument vectors, and passes them all at once to the function. For instance,

```r
outer(seq_along(dfspl), seq_along(dfspl), function(a, b) { browser(); 1; })
# Called from: FUN(X, Y, ...)
debug at #1: [1] 1
# Browse[2]> 
a
# [1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
# Browse[2]> 
b
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
# Browse[2]>
```

What we ultimately want to do is find the intersection of each pair of studies.

```r
dfspl[[1]]
# [1] 1 3 2
dfspl[[3]]
# [1] 2 3
intersect(dfspl[[1]], dfspl[[3]])
# [1] 3 2
length(intersect(dfspl[[1]], dfspl[[3]]))
# [1] 2
```

Granted, we are doing it twice (once for 1 and 3, once for 3 and 1, which is the same result), so this is a little inefficient ... it would be better to filter them to only look at the upper or lower half and transferring it to the other.

---

Edited for a more efficient process (only calculating each intersection pair *once*, and never calculating self-intersection.)

```r
eg <- expand.grid(a = seq_along(dfspl), b = seq_along(dfspl))
eg <- eg[ eg$a < eg$b, ]
eg
#   a b
# 4 1 2
# 7 1 3
# 8 2 3
lens <- lengths(Map(intersect, dfspl[eg$a], dfspl[eg$b]))
lens
# 1 1 2       ## btw, these are just names, from eg$a
# 1 2 0 
out <- matrix(nrow = length(dfspl), ncol = length(dfspl))
out[ cbind(eg$a, eg$b) ] <- lens
out
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   NA    1    2
# [2,]   NA   NA    0
# [3,]   NA   NA   NA
out[ lower.tri(out) ] <- out[ upper.tri(out) ]
diag(out) <- lengths(dfspl)
out
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    3    1    2
# [2,]    1    1    0
# [3,]    2    0    2
```

Comment: Apologies for my simplistic R understanding, but how did you create dfspl? It doesn't seem to work when I use the df in my post. My hope is the final object will have the dimensions of the number of metas, not the number of studies.

Answer (score 1):

Same idea as @r2evans, also Base R (and a bit less eloquent) (edited as required):

```
# Create df using sample data: 

df <- data.frame(metas = c(1,1,1,2,3,3), studies = c(1,7,2,1,2,3))

# Test for equality between the values in the metas vector and the rest of 
# of the values in the dataframe -- Construct symmetric matrix from vector: 

m1 <- diag(v1); m1[,1] <- m1[1,] <- v1 <- rowSums(data.frame(sapply(df$metas, `==`, 
                                                                    unique(unlist(df)))))

# Coerce matrix to dataframe setting the names as desired; dropping non matches:

df_2 <- setNames(data.frame(m1[which(rowSums(m1) > 0), which(colSums(m1) > 0)]),
                 paste0("v", 1:ncol(m1[which(rowSums(m1) > 0), which(colSums(m1) > 0)])))
```

Comment: This seems close, but it doesn't work when I have a non-symmetric number of studies, e.g.: df <- data.frame(metas = c(1,1,1,2,3,3), studies = c(1,7,2,1,2,3))

Comment: @arrrrRgh Edited as required, please give the solution an upvote if you have found it useful.